# Why does the Elixir tag info page say it was created 7 years ago?

Tags: bug, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elixir/info says that the tag was created 7 years ago, which I thought was strange because the language isn't that old. The oldest question seems to be from 2012.

Comment: It could've existed prior to 2012, been "burninated", then came back to life in 2012.

Comment: Yeah, considering the timestamp given on hover is also from 2012, the math there is clearly wrong. Looks like a bunch of calculations for tags older than 1 year are getting botched.

Comment: If a tag is actually *burninated* - removed from the system entirely - then it is well and truly gone, @Zizouz212; if it's ever re-created, then the tag will have a new creation date.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah... Interesting. So tags are basically ghost like? Disappearing without a trace? :P

Comment: Well, there you get into the wrinkle that is revision history, @Zizouz212. Tags can be deleted by removing them from all questions, but that leaves a trace of them in the revision histories. The tag - as a distinct record in a database table - is still gone, but there's still the evidence that it once existed. However... Tags can also be removed in such a way that even revision histories are purged. For example, merges remove all trace of one tag from the site. So if [tag:elixir] had been merged into [tag:python-elixir], this question wouldn't have come up...

Comment: Clearly this is a problem due to caching

Comment: Reason for Elixir tags being the way they are: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184533/179419, please don't merge them...

Answer (score 32):

Heh... So, the time shown in the hover-text is the creation date of the tag wiki.

But the *name* shown is the creator of the tag itself, the first person to ever use it on the site. And the tag *was* created [7 years ago by Swati](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/192345/revisions), in a question about *[Python's Elixir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Elixir/)* rather than erlang's.

Leaving this marked as a bug, since at very least we should be using the same timestamp for both the relative date and the hovertext.

Comment: I think this if my first bug post on meta. Am I supposed to mark this answer accepted? Or is that only for when the bug is fixed?

Comment: Wait for a fix.

Comment: @Shog9 Are you saying that if the OP accepts this answer before the bug is solved, it is no longer marked as an active bug?

Comment: @MrLister asking the real questions. I have often wondered this too. Presumably people who need to fix issues wouldn't leave whether or not they see them up to Meta users, so I'm going to guess that there is an internal bug list that is not based on accepted/not-accepted Meta questions.

Comment: Doesn't matter for that, @mrlister. Just annoying if someone writes an answer after fixing it.