# Earned badges became invisible on this Stack Overflow profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

[image: Stack Overflow profile screenshot]

I went to my Stack Overflow profile page and clicked on the settings button (which badge to track). All my earned bronze badges were invisible.

#### Edit 1:

It looks like this bug is with the '[Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi)' badge. I just revisited the activities performed today, and I have cast 40 votes. The system took time to assign the badge. **It assigned the badge & made the rest of the badges invisible**.

To confirm this bug, I have cast my votes in another profile ('Ask Ubuntu'), and the bug was reproduced.

Comment: ! Forget your achievements and work towards the next one :)

Comment: Reproduced with Safari 9.0.3 on OS X 10.11.3

Comment: @shyju, hehe..... I can't leave a bug unnoticed. ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Vox Populi in particular. I can repro it on sites where I haven't earned that badge. It affects the display of any badge that you have earned, and is therefore indicated with a green checkmark in the top-right corner.

It appears to be a CSS problem. There is a `before` pseudo-element in each of the badge `div`s, set to display as a block with a solid background color. Because its top, left, bottom, and right properties are all set to 0, it has 100% width and 100% height. Therefore, the solid-color background is covering up the entire contents of those `div`s.

```
.popup-badges .all-badge-progress .completed:before {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f7f8f8;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you remove the background-color style, the problem goes away because the element becomes transparent. It also goes away if you remove the `before` pseudo-element entirely. I'm not really sure why it is there.

It is, in fact, *not* there on the badges that are displayed correctly. Which are also the badges that lack green checkmarks in the top-right corner. The `before` pseudo-element looks like a mistake, perhaps introduced by accident when the `after` pseudo-element was added to display the green checkmark?

---

**Update:** As of February 22, 2016, [this bug has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275994/153008) network-wide. The purpose of the `before` pseudo-element was apparently to give the badge cell a background color, but the CSS wizards saw the error of their ways. Instead of using a hack like changing its Z order, they removed the pseudo-element altogether and just set a background color. As a special bonus, a hover effect was added for a hot-tracking effect.

Comment: on a different note, should an answer regarding a bug be accepted before the bug is fixed? Just read somewhere else that on meta that it should not be. Just asking.

Comment: So many CSS problems off late. Some one must have been sacked at StackExchange and he ripped off all code before leaving :D

Comment: @SajibAcharya accepted answers don't mean very much on meta, so it isn't much of a big deal as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Sajib Acharya, Do you mean asker should accept only when the bug is fixed ?

Comment: @Raju, I am not sure of this procedure, so I asked for opinion over the matter. I read this as a discussion somewhere on meta itself while they were discussing over a bug, so I asked. Read the comments following this answer in the post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317216/3640307 That is why I asked.

Comment: @SajibAcharya,  Thanks for sharing the link. I could see a comment from moderator '**Wait for the fix**'. Hence, I have unaccepted the answer.

Comment: @SajibAcharya Precedent is to wait for an answer by a SO developer saying that it's fixed.

Comment: It is Meta. There are no rules, other than don't take anything too seriously. You can accept or not accept. The developers don't track acceptance to determine completion, they have [meta-tag:status-completed] tags instead. Then again, I don't care about acceptance, either.

Answer (score 4):

This is a network wide bug. You can check it in *[Unable to see completed badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275976/unable-to-see-completed-badges/275977#comment894217_275977)*.

And besides @Cody Gray's answer, the answer given there fixes the issue for now:

> The problem is with the `.popup-badges .all-badge-progress
>   .completed:before`. It has a `z-index` of `0`, where `-1` would fit
>   better (the `:before` on the `div` with that class takes care of the
>   background).
>
> If you change that the badges are back:
>
> [image: unbroken]

Comment: Thanks & Yes, issue is fixed.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, I guess. They were using that `before` pseudo-element to change the background color. I was wondering why it was there in the first place. Seems like a massive hack, though... (Edit: [Hynes agreed with me.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275994/153008))